# What is Androids Local "URL" Phone Gap,

Tags: android, cordova

Does a local "URL" for Android Phone Gap applications exist?

If so, could someone point me in the direction of it?

Something like "Local://%AppName%/www/file.html" ?

Comment: What does "local" mean? A file on internal storage? A file on external storage? A file that you have packaged with your app? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not 100% sure about your want to achieve.

If you want the file system path where your app resides then you have to first get the file system and the point to the app root directory. There you can pick certain files.

This is part of my current code, bit be aware to adjust the code to fits your needs, this was written for as is for my own convenience.

```
var app_FileSystem;                     // Application file system path. Variable to ease access to the file system instead of instatiating it each time is required

// Get the application data path, NOTE: first run Get Application File system function.
function GetAppDataPath ()
{
    var appDataPath;
    appDataPath = app_FileSystem.root.fullPath;

    return appDataPath;
}

function GetAppFS ()
{
    var self = this;
   self.state = "";                     // store the state of the process for debuggin purposes
   self.fileSystem = {};

    window.requestFileSystem ( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFileSystemSuccess, dispatchFailure );

    /**
     *
     * Called when we receive a valid file system. Once we do that, we need to ask for all
     * the documents within the file system.
     *
     */
    function getFileSystemSuccess ( fileSystem )
    {
        self.state = "Received File System";
         self.fileSystem = fileSystem;
        app_FileSystem = fileSystem;
         OnFSReady (); // trigger a function that do something one the FS is ready
    };

    function dispatchFailure ( e )
    {
        console.log ("While " + self.state + ", encountered error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
         alert ("File Sys ERROR ");
    };  
};
```

**EDIT:**
Obviously you can code all of that in a shorter version, but is what I have to help you quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a local "URL" for Android Phone Gap applications exist?

Yes

> If so, could someone point me in the direction of it?

That won't be possible; it would depend on the location of your files as in folders.

--

You should refer to this resource it will help you better understand URLs better

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: So, what would be the path? I know about "paths" though, what would it be for an android device with an app called "App" (for example).

Comment: It would be in the form of something like the following: "file:///yourappname/www/index.html"