# Read the xml file located in the assets/www using phonegap file reader

Tags: cordova

I have an xml file (demo.xml) in assets/www/sample folder. I wants to read the file using phonegap file reader so that i can get the base64 encoded format of the file content. How can I do this?

Comment: This question has been answered several times. Be sure to always check similar questions before just posting a new one. You can look at my answer here for the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777945/what-is-androids-local-url-phone-gap/20788504#20788504

Comment: Also clarify if you are asking to read the file inside the www folder or asking how to read in certain file format.